# XML file couldn't be detected after windows service setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, windows-installer

I have created a windows service. I do the setup of the service using the windows installer. 
I have one XML file like a config file. Whenever i debug windows service with attaching the debug project it works fine. But after the installation i can see the event saying couldn't find the example.xml file in C:\Windows\system32. It's a repeating problem. Can anyone tell me whats going on with this. Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an installer problem. Windows Services are always started with System32 as the current directory.  Add this line to the Main() method in your Program.cs prior to firing up any services.

```
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName).DirectoryName;
```

Comment: +1: possible approach, also I'd recommend @spender's (+1 too) approach to explicitly compute path to config file instead of relying on Current folder (even if you set it - some other piece of code may change it and loading will be broken again in even more confusing way).

Comment: The reason I suggest this approach is if the poster doesn't understand this behavior he's likely to have other dependencies downstream.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely file is just not where you are looking for it.

Chances are that your code looks in "current working folder" which during debugging in VS is the same as application, but in case of starting as service/from command line is different.

Make sure your code loads file from location you expect the file to be (i.e. next to the application), but not from some relative path (like "myfile.xml").

Comment: I tried doing this i event copied xml to the installation directory but the problem is same. Is there a way to make setup copy the xml file to system32 folder?

Comment: Copying the XML to System32 is not a best practice. In your service code, you need to use reflection to get the location of the running assembly.  Convert that to it's directory full name and do a Path.Combine() to get the proper location of the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saving stuff in the Windows folders? Unless there's a *really* good reason to do so, this is **bad**. Install your config in the same place that your app is running and get the file path with:

```
var folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var configPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, configFileName);
```

Comment: Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));

            ConfigurationPath = @"config_file.xml"; using this worked for me thanks... i got your idea.

Comment: @nzdev, please consider up-voting Christopher Painter's solution which you essentially used...

Comment: How you do it doesn't matter to me.  The important part is to understand that windows services start off in System32.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your service is not running as Administrator.  If the service is not running as Administrator,  then it won't be able to read the files under system32 folder.

Change the service properties to run as Administrator.  That should fix the issue.

Comment: That is not quite correct. Much of system32 can be read by non-Administrators.