# EntityFramework metadata resources

Tags: c#, entity-framework, metadata

I have problem with set up correct metadata res in app.config.

I am creating WCF server application which provide access to database.

My ssdl, msl and csdl files are in Assembly/EntityModel/...

When i hosted this WCF server in console app, my connection string looks like:

```
<add name="xpdir2ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=.\EntityModel\xpdir2Model.csdl|.\EntityModel\xpdir2Model.ssdl|.\EntityModel\xpdir2Model.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;Port=5432;Encoding=WIN1250;Server=localhost;Database=xpdir2_mvc;UserId=postgres;Password=postgres&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

and everythings works correctly. After i change hosting from console app to windows service, it stops working. I know, when i install service, its current directory is something like Windows/Wow64/...

So i was trying to set metadata files as embedded resource. I use:

```
 <add name="xpdir2ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.xpdir2Model.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.xpdir2Model.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.xpdir2Model.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;Port=5432;Encoding=WIN1250;Server=localhost;Database=xpdir2_mvc;UserId=postgres;Password=postgres&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

But this doesn't works. It throws exception:

```
{System.Data.MappingException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
EntityModel.xpdir2Model.msl(5,4) : error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the       EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer xpdir2ModelContainer.
```

When is use absolute paths to metadata files, everything works. Does anybody knows, what is the problem?

Thanks. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution. I am changing Environment.CurrentDirectory to directory, from which was service installed.

I used: [XML file couldn't be detected after windows service setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418918/xml-file-couldnt-be-detected-after-windows-service-setup)

Regards